# Difference between the tensorflow 'freeze_graph' and the object detection api's 'export_inference_graph'

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I tried to freeze my resnet_ssd graphs with the tensorflow's own 'freeze_graph' script. This was a failure.
The weird s that the 'export_inference_graph.py' -that is recommended to use here - calls the same function deep inside, but the passed parameters are different (for example the freeze_graph reads the 'architecture' from the graph.pbtxt, the export_inference_graph does not need the graph.pbtxt file, but the 'architecture' is not the same! (you can make a quick experiment via print out the input_graph_def in the freeze_graph.py's freeze_graph_with_def_protos function in the tensorflow's tree (both of the method calls this function))

So, which method should be used to freeze resnet+ssd object detection model and why not the other?

Thankx for the answer in advance,
Karoly